Как разбить слишком большой класс в Blazor с использованием partial?
У меня есть Blazor-компонент с partial-классом, который стал слишком большим (более 1000 строк) и содержит много логики: обработчики для кнопок, методы для работы с таблицей (grid), инициализацию данных и т.д. Я хотела бы разделить его на несколько файлов, чтобы упростить поддержку кода и улучшить читаемость.
Можно ли создать несколько файлов с partial-классами для одного и того же компонента, чтобы разделить логику? Если да, как правильно это сделать?

Это самоответ на вопрос, получается? Прямо совсем самостоятельный, или по мотивам какого-то ответа на английском СО, документации MS и т.п.? Если по мотивам, то лучше добавить ссылок. И точно дублей на русском СО нет, искали? )

@CrazyElf, это самостоятельные мучения рефакторинга))) //а. дублей не нашла б. ссылки всегда оставляю, если оригинал есть - это эксклюзив) в. Если есть ваш ответ, то только за, делитесь, мне только на пользу и тем, кто будет искать

Нельзя ли какие-то части, например Grid с его логикой сделать отдельным компонентом?
Нельзя ли вынести бизнес-логику в сервис, который будет запрошен при помощи @Inject?
Использование вложенных компонентов может способствовать разделению ответственности между частями кода, возможно также, что какие-то части получится переиспользовать в другом месте.

@EugeneMaksimov, благодарю за отзыв. да,сервисы так и так отделены, и инжектятся. А вот разделить компонент на компоненты это круто, в реалии наверняка так и буду делать в дальнейшем, нотам тоже свои нюансы, вызвать и заставить отзываться, не всегда получается, поэтому пока что весь основной (так скажем) на одной странице. Хотя там есть отдельные компоненты в нем. То есть, то, что легко я сразу выпиливаю, а что не скоблится пока оставлять приходится.

Да, в Blazor можно использовать несколько partial-классов для одного компонента, чтобы разделить логику на разные файлы. Все классы с одинаковым именем и модификатором partial будут восприняты компилятором как один класс.
Вот как выглядит "дерево"

"Основной" partial класс наследует : IAsyncDisposable и содержит основные методы загрузки
namespace Blazor9.Components.Pages.MyComponent1
{
    public partial class MyPageRazor : IAsyncDisposable
    {

        [Inject]
        public IMyService? myService{ get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await LoadGridData();
        }

        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
        }
    }
}

MyPageRazor.Button.cs, как видно уже ничего не наследует, и название класса MyPageRazor
namespace Blazor9.Components.Pages.MyComponent1
{
    public partial class MyPageRazor
    {
        private void OnButtonClick()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Button clicked!");
        }
    }
}

и третий partial класс, к примеру для логики таблицы MyPageRazor.Grid.cs
namespace Blazor9.Components.Pages.MyComponent1
{
    public partial class MyPageRazor
    {
        public List<GridDataModel> GridData { get; set; } = new();

        private async Task LoadGridData()
        {
            GridData = await myService.LoadDataAsync();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}

сама разметка MyPageRazor.razor для наглядности
@page "/mypage"

@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h3>My Page</h3>

<button @onclick="OnButtonClick">Click Me</button>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in GridData)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ID</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


Так Blazor или Razor?

@aepot, Blazor, там тоже разор компоненты, но немного другие по-моему, поэтому саму метку разор не поставила, классы тоже...и вообще только блазор метка подходит тут

https://i.sstatic.net/6e9A5hBM.png

Ок. Ещё partial за пределами дотнетовского дизайна - это антипаттерн. В 99% случаев оно добавляет путаницы, а не наоборот. В общем, его конечно никто не запрещает использовать, но будьте максимально внимательны. Лично я бы не стал. Если компонент перегружен, скорее пошёл бы по SRP/SOLID смотреть, где разбить логику.

@aepot, В Blazor разделение на .razor и partial class .razor.cs — стандарт для отделения логики от разметки. Это помогает поддерживать чистоту кода и делает компонент более читаемым. Так все делают, даже в примерах дока Майкрософт. Мой вопрос встал, когда сам partial класс вырос

Хорошо, но GridDataModel здесь всё-таки может унести куда-то в модели?

@aepot, это просто пример, GridDataModel обязательно надо в папочку Data или как у меня Models //я тестировала, и поэтому класс создала в .cs partial, а так модели должны лежать отдельно

LoadGridData() - этот метод, вероятно, должен быть в другом классе (репозитории) для работы с БД/файлами (откуда данные грузятся). Возвращать он должен не void, а коллекцию. / Аналогично, код из баттон-кликов, если его больше одной строки, выносим в классы бизнес-логики. / В итоге все методы в компоненте худеют до одной строки. Он становится небольшим. Не?

@AlexanderPetrov, вообще пишут вверху html разметку, а внизу в блоке @code{} пишут все методы из разметки. Это для маленького проекта, маленьких страниц, но если страница большая делят на .cs и разметку. Куда я могу вынести LoadGridData() ? Он же в разметке нужен для загрузки таблицы. //где эти классы бизнес-логики => можете "дерево" показать ?это не сервисы? но сам сервис, чтоб вызвать, я inject-ю сервис, но вызываю опять же на разоре. Не? => незнаю, давайте ответ с примером
